# How can I keep my main tkinter window from freezing when opening another file (.pyw)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code needs to run a program that will download images and will run indefinitely until told to stop. The problem is keeping the Tkinter window alive, so I run the code, it starts working but the Tkinter window is frozen.
I have tried threading a bit but it's just difficult to understand. The commented-out part is the threading I tried before but didn't work. And the `root.update_idletasks()` is supposed to refresh the widgets but that didn't work.

```
def mainmenuControls(menuState):
    if menuState == "start" and selectionsExist():
        mainMenu("started")
        subprocess.run("run.bat", shell=True)
        root.update_idletasks()
        #thread = threading.Thread(target=subprocess.run("console.pyw", shell=True))
        #thread.start()
        mainMenu()
```

Comment: Your attempt at threading called `subprocess.run()` *immediately*, in the main thread, thus causing the same problem as the non-threaded version.  You need to pass a *function* to `Thread()` (`subprocess.run`, in this case), and specify its parameters via `args=` and `kwargs=` - this allows it to actually be called in the thread.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
def anewprocess():    
     subprocess.run("run.bat", shell=True)

def mainmenuControls(menuState):
        if menuState == "start" and selectionsExist():
            mainMenu("started")                 
            thread = threading.Thread(target=anewprocess)
            thread.start()
            mainMenu()
```

Here,what happens is that `anewprocess` function will be run in a new Thread.
I guess this might solve your problem

Note that all the arguments you want to give to a Thread should be in tuples.
Eg:`Thread(target=somefunction,args=(arg1,arg2,arg3))`
If you want to know more about threading,see this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/.